# Improving the computational time of R for loops

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

Trying to run a spline function by rows (690075) in a dataframe (Camera1)  with 4096 columns (each column represents a position on the x axis) where the input variable to the function is a column in another dataset of the same length (test$vr) using a for loop; but I am having serious computational time issues.

I have tried converting the dataframe to a matrix and storing the output in a list amongst others, but to no avail. I have to do this for 2 other dataframes (camera2,camera3) of the same size.

**Code**

```
 # Note camera1 and test$vr are of the same length
 # Initialize
 final.data1 <- data.frame()

 #new wavelength range
 y1 <- round(seq(from = 4714 , to = 4900, length.out = 4096),3)

 system.time({
   for (i in 1:690075) {
       w1 = (as.numeric(colnames(camera1[-1]))) * (1.0 + test$vr[i]/299792.458)
       my.data1<-as.data.frame(t(splinefun(x = w1, y = camera1[i,][-1])(y1)))
       colnames(my.data1)=y1
       final.data1 <- bind_rows(final.data1, my.data1)
     } })
```

Running on a Ubuntu box with 344GB ram and 30 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 @ 2.30GHz

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Try reading up on parrelisation in `R`, then you can make use of those 30 cores rather than just using one. [Here is a good place to start](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check this out

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the data it's not easy to optimize your code, but I would start with something along the lines of the following.

```
final.data1 <- matrix(nrow = 690075, ncol = 4096)

#new wavelength range
y1 <- round(seq(from = 4714 , to = 4900, length.out = 4096), 3)

system.time({
   w1 <- (as.numeric(colnames(camera1[-1]))) * (1.0 + test$vr/299792.458)
   for (i in 1:690075) {
       my.data1 <- t(splinefun(x = w1[i], y = camera1[i, ][-1])(y1))
       final.data1[i, ] <- my.data1
   }
})

final.data1 <- as.data.frame(final.data1)
colnames(final.data1) <- y1
```

Explanation:

1. I start by defining an object of class `matrix` to hold the results. I believe I got the dimensions of your final `data.frame` right. This reduces the running time because

   - Matrices are much faster than data frames, they are just folded vectors and indexing is fast. Data frames, on the contrary, are lists that can hold all types of data, numeric, character, logical, other lists, etc., and therefore it's slow to access their members.
   - By reserving the result's full memory in one operation saves R's memory management routines a lot of work. To extend `final.data1` every iteration through the loop, is very time consuming.
2. `w1` is computed outside the loop, taking advantage of R's vectorized nature. Besides, you were repeating the computation of `as.numeric(colnames(camera1[-1]))` 690k times!

Test this code and if it doesn't produce the same final result, just say so and I will see if I can do something to debug it.

Comment: Thank you Rui for the detailed breakdown. I will implement this now and report back.

Comment: So I am getting an error with computing w1 outside the loop. 
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Every value in `test$vr` needs to be multiplied along `(as.numeric(colnames(camera1[-1])))` creating 690075 rows.

Comment: @aastroh What are the values of `length(colnames(camera1[-1]))` and `length(test$vr)`?

Comment: `(colnames(camera1[-1])` is a column vector with values like `y1..ie 4714-4900` so `length = 4096`
and
`test$vr` is a column vector of numeric values where each value needs to be iterated through `w1` to generate a new set of values similar to `4714-4900`. This has `length 690075`.

Answer (score 3):

First remove all instructions that can be done once, and put them outside the for loop. For example: `colnames` and `as.numeric`.

Second, try to vectorize. It seems that the `w1` calculation can be vectorized, and so estimated once outside the for loop, by just removing the `[i]`.

Third, initialize the `final.data1` to the final dimension. For each row added to this data.frame, R will create a new data.frame with one more row, then remove the previous data.frame. It will take long time. Thus, `final.data1 <- matrix(NA, ncol=length(y1), nrow=NROW)`.

And finally, if you want to use more than one core, try to replace the for loop by the parallelized `foreach loop`. It is possible if all rows are independant:

```
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(25, type="FORK") # FORK not usable in Windows
registerDoSNOW(cl) # register the cluster
clusterExport(cl, c("objects", "needed", "by", "each", "iteration"), envir=environment()) # for example y1, w1 and camera1
final.data1<- foreach(i=icount(NROW), .combine=rbind, inorder=FALSE) %dopar%
{
  # your R code
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Ah I couldn't work out the structure of the parallelised version; I will try and see if I can use this if. Thank you!